# iPhone: Moving objects in unison

Tags: iphone, animation, uiscrollview

I'm moving multiple objects around an iPhone screen, and changing the field of view at the same time. This looks jagged, as the different object moves happen at different times, especially from the call to zoomToRect to move the view around the scrollView they all live in.

If these were the old days of computer animation, I'd say I want a frame buffer to keep things moving all together at the instant. But I imagine there's a higher level way to do that in iOS.

What's the easiest/cleanest way to make all these moves go off in the same instant?

Edit: To clarify, I made a separate question for keeping the ScrollView moving in lockstep with an object inside it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Core Animation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW1

The simplest way is with a block like:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    // do all kinds of repositioning, alpha changes, etc.
}];
```

As always, check the docs. There may be some ordering concerns if you're using a ScrollView `zoomToRect:animated:` at the same time.

Comment: Oh, I do check the docs. But there's the old AppKit way of doing things. There's the Core Animation way of doing things. You can literally access a frame buffer still. You could set everything up as OpenGL. And those are just the ways I can think of off the top of my head. The docs tell you which methods are possible, but not which are sane.

Comment: And within each of those approaches, there's a different way you'd get the Frame Buffer effect...

Comment: Good point. Leaning on UIView's CoreAnimation backed layer would be the best "high level" approach; plus the inline block syntax makes it very clear and concise, in my opinion.